# Selecting the right pattern for adding in robots.txt

Tags: views, google-search-console

I've some views with exposed filters but I find that Googlebot is indexing them. In short I don't want any of those Views content by generated exposed filters to be seen by Google.

[This page](https://drupal.org/node/345620) has listed more about it.

I want a pattern which should work for almost all views by restricting access to content generated by changing exposed filters.

Will this cause any issues?:

```
Disallow:/*&sort_order=*
```

Assuming we always specify sort order in Views. Is there any other module(s) which may generate url containing this parameter?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about network standards rather than Drupal. Changing robots.txt will not affect how your Drupal works in any way, and you apparently aren't asking about generating this file dynamically, or about replicating it's effect with things Drupal can send to user agent.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr but it will not have any effects on Drupal site at all. It will only have effects on Google / Bing sites. That's why I think it's better on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). Well, vote is open.

Comment: @Mołot I'm asking for parameter name which may not conflict with any other Drupal modules and not about Robots rules. What is the use of asking in Webmasters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the line you suggest to you site's `robots.txt` will stop *googlebot* from crawling the URLs that contain this string.

However, what attributes modules add to the URL is up to the module.  You need to examine the source code of the modules you use to avoid any conflict. I doubt there is anyone here with encyclopedic knowledge of what attributes *every* module use (there are more than 20000 on [Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/project/modules)).

Instead of searching through modules for possible conflicts, I would invent a "magic" string that is pretty much guaranteed to be unique or not used for any *other* purpose by a Drupal module (e.g. "dontcrawlme") and add that "magic" string to the path to the views I don't want crawled, or add a dummy attribute with "magic" string as name to those views, then Disallow any crawling of an URL containing the "magic" string. This is simpler and more robust than relying on `sort_order=` being unique for exposed filters in Views.

You need to take care not to overwrite your custom additions to `robots.txt` when you do a minor upgrade of the Drupal core.

Note that wildcards is not part of the Robot Exclusion Standards (but are supported by *googlebot* and *bing*), so don't expect any rule with wildcards to be widely recognised by robots.